# Ask a user for credentials in casperjs using system.stdin while hiding typing

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, casperjs

So using CasperJS 1.1.0-beta3, I can get input from the user at the console via...

```
  system.stdout.writeLine('User account:');
  var useraccount = system.stdin.readLine();
  system.stdout.writeLine('User account password:');
  var password = system.stdin.readLine();
```

And use those variables later to fill in a form.

My question is in two parts. Are there security implications of doing this? For example, is this user input saved to any casper / phantom logs?

Secondly, is there a command to hide (don't echo back keyboard strokes) the typed characters, or failing that, put background and foreground to identical colors?

Alternatively, is there a better way? That is how does one do front end testing when authentication is required but you don't want to save a password in the .js file?

Comment: Probably not. Are we talking cross-platform or only windows or Linux?

Comment: I work primarily on Linux